# How can I count the number of row instances where a value from any of the columns is set to true

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, boolean

How can I count the number of rows where any of the column fields is true? or
How can I count the number of users where any of the columns is set to true?

Example:

```
User    Name    Last Name
1   TRUE    TRUE
2   FALSE   TRUE
3   TRUE    FALSE
4   FALSE   FALSE
5   FALSE   FALSE
```

For the example above the number of rows or users where the Name or Last Name is true, is equal to 3 (User 1, User 2, and User 3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IN` condition:

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where true in (name, last_name)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where name = true 
   or last_name = true;
```

`where name = true or last_name = true` can be shortened to `where name or last_name`

But the first query is easier to adapt when more columns should be included e.g. `true in (name, last_name, nick_name)`

---

To get the number of columns that are true, you can use a trick in Postgres where casting a `boolean` to a number yields `1` or `0` so to get the number of columns that are `true` just add them up:

```
select name::int + last_name::int as "Number of true values"
from the_table
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/23a4a/1

Answer (score 0):

You can Achieve your goal using this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE [row1] = true OR [row2] = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the remark, I edited the LIKE but the [ ] is to tell him where he puts his own data not to write them as they are.